# FMX Delphi ComboBox Sorted not present

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I need to sort a ComboBox on FMX receive a message error: "undeclared identifier"

var c: TComboBox;

c.sorted := true;  //Error undeclared identifier

On VCL work fine.

thanks for help
Giorgio

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, things aren't that simple in FMX since, as you've found, a TComboBox in FMX has no Sorted property.

Once you tune into FMX's wavelength there is a simple solution to this.

What you need to do is to call `Sort` on your ComboxBox and supply as its argument a `TFmxObjectSortCompare` function which sorts the Items as you wish.  Obviously this is a lot more flexible than just setting a `Sorted` property to true, but is a bit more work.  Fortunately, you can do it fairly easily by supplying the Compare function as an anonymous method:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var 
  Compare: TFMXObjectSortCompare;
begin
  ComboBox1.Items.Add('C');
  ComboBox1.Items.Add('B');
  ComboBox1.Items.Add('A');
  Compare := function(Item1, Item2: TFmxObject): Integer
  begin
    if TListBoxItem(Item1).Text = TListBoxItem(Item2).Text then
      Result := 0
    else
    if TListBoxItem(Item1).Text > TListBoxItem(Item2).Text then
      Result := 1
    else
      Result := -1;
  end;

  ComboBox1.Sort(Compare);
end;
```

PS:  I had no idea how to do this before I read your q and started reading around the subject.

Comment: thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Hi, sorry let me know where is "tick" icon... thanks

Comment: At the top left of my answer are 'Up' and 'Down' icons for up- and down-voting the answer and the tick icon should be just below rge 'Down' one.

Comment: Still not found the 'tick' icon?